# How register a ajaxcontrolkit?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Multiview control, inside the Views I have controls with ajaxcontrol kit extenders.

I'm trying to set the multiview in Page_Load dynamically with:

```
MultiView1.SetActiveView(ViewWeek11);
```

But when I do it I get:

> Extender control 'CalendarExtender_Date' is not a registered extender
>   control. Extender controls must be registered using
>   RegisterExtenderControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().

I have read many post about the problem, it seems that I have to use

```
 protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

and inside it, register the controls, but I coudnt find an example and honestly I dont get it, I dont know how to do it, can somebody give me an example?

Comment: Have you tried calling `MultiView1.SetActiveView` in `OnPreRender`?

Answer (score 0):

> Extender control 'X' is not a registered extender control

That's an issue already registered in the DevExpress Support Center, below are the  details as DevExpress Team depicts the solution.

> This issue is caused by specifics of the AjaxControlToolkit controls
> that register resources in the PreRender event handler. This event is
> NOT raised when processing a callback request initiated via the
> ICallbackEventHandler routine (like it is implemented in DevExpress
> ASP.NET controls). See the K18387: The Concept of Callbacks KB Article
> for a detailed explanation. As a result, the mentioned error occurs.
>
> To resolve this issue, proceed with any of the following ways:
>
> - Replace the AjaxControlToolkit extender with the corresponding
>   DevExpress ASP.NET counterpart. Consult the Support Team to find the appropriate analog;
> - Disable the callback mode for the used DevExpress ASP.NET control by setting the EnableCallBacks property to False (if this control offers such a property). See the Use AJAX Extenders in the EditForm template example regarding this;
> - Use the UpdatePanel when it is necessary to add/initialize an extender dynamically and refresh its content programmatically instead of using the ASPxCallbackPanel container.

See https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center